# msi call from other server

Tags: windows

is it possible to call msi file from other server at the time of setup install on the client system in vs2005??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly trigger the installation of an MSI installer on a remote machine using a custom action, given that you have all required permissions.

Without knowing your exact scenario it is difficult to give you further advice though.

Comment: when we run setup its takes msi from local machine but we want, it should call msi from other server

Answer (score 0):

when we run setup its takes msi from local machine but we want, it should call msi from other server